# fedora 17 with fedup 0.7

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I get the bug described [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F20_bugs#fedup-07-fail) when trying to upgrade to Fedora 20 from Fedora 17.

> The symptom is that the first stage of upgrade (before rebooting)
>   works successfully, but when you reboot to complete the upgrade, the
>   second stage begins but almost immediately aborts and reboots back to
>   your previous Fedora system.

Guess I'm running fedup 0.7 (see terminal output)

```
[root@localhost mylaptop]# yum install fedup
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Package fedup-0.7.3-5.fc17.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

There is a mention about getting fedup 0.8 from updates repository but that's in my repolist:

```
[root@localhost mylaptop]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
repo id                         repo name                                 status
adobe-linux-x86_64              Adobe Systems Incorporated                     2
fedora/17/x86_64                Fedora 17 - x86_64                        27,033
updates/17/x86_64               Fedora 17 - x86_64 - Updates              13,163
repolist: 40,198
```

The solution described is to update fedup to 0.8 but as you can see in the output it won't because 0.7 is installed and latest version. What am I to do next?

**[UPDATE]**

Got the fedup package from http://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/fedup/0.8.0/3.fc18/noarch/fedup-0.8.0-3.fc18.noarch.rpm

After installing (double clicking the file); as root copied the files I've already downloaded using fedup 0.7

```
cp -R /var/lib/fedora-upgrade /var/lib/system-upgrade
cp -R /var/tmp/fedora-upgrade /var/tmp/system-upgrade
```

Running fedup again as root:

```
 fedup --network 20 --nogpgcheck
```

**[UPDATE]**

After that it will boot through the update upgrade and boots into .... Fedora 17 :(

Can reboot again and have the upgrade option again that will boot into 17 again minus a working wifi.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the updates-testing repo:

```
su -c 'yum install fedup --enablerepo=updates-testing'
```

For additional information see: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Updates_Testing

Generally you leave this repo disabled unless you are involved in testing ;)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, as you can see in the question both repos are already enabled, when executing the command you suggested I get `Package fedup-0.7.3-5.fc17.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do` Looks like the package is not available for FC17 at all: https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/fedup/overview/

Comment: You do not have "updates-testing" enabled. Try the command I gave you please.

Comment: Fedora 17 is beyond end of life, so your upgrade is not going to be supported. You can try either downloading fedup for Fedora 18 or a fresh install. It is quite a jump to go from 17->20 and a fresh install may be faster and easier.

Comment: I did try the command as you gave it and the output of that is the one posted in the previous comment. Downloaded fedup of FC18 and will try that. fedup.spec says >= fc17 so hope it'll work.

Comment: If the f18 package does not work, I think your best option would then be to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update to the next version first. Then the next and so on. Skipping versions is not recommended.

And don't forget to add the product option for the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having the exact same symptomes as you describe when trying to upgrade Fedora 17 to 20 using fedup and using your steps to solve it.

My final solution was updating to Fedora 18 using the yum way described [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum#Fedora_17_-.3E_Fedora_18)

After this step I was able to go from Fedora 18 to 20 using fedup like you wrote.

```
  sudo fedup --network 20 --nogpgcheck
```

Since I tried your described way in the beginning I also had fedup 0.8 installed when I was trying. So without this step you might still need to update fedup 0.7 to 0.8 under Fedora 18 using

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=updates-testing update fedup
```

You can check with `sudo yum info fedup` what version you have installed.